# Создать класс по строковой переменной

Tags: php, ооп

И так, есть класс:

```
`namespace Controllers;
class IndexController
{
...
}`
```

Как в другом классе использовать методы этого класса?

```
namespace Library\MainFunction;
class MainFunction
{
public function foo()
  {
    $class = 'Controllers\\IndexController';
    $obj = new $class; \\ ошибка  Class 'Controllers\IndexController' not found
  }
}
```

Что я делаю не так и как правильно? Вызов через строковую переменную, потому что контроллер будет меняться.

Comment: А вы уверены, что вы подключили файл с `IndexController` классом в файл с `MainFunction` классом?

Comment: composer сделал это за меня. Если я вызову класс напрямую без переменной, то все нормально отрабатывает.

Comment: `\\Controllers\\IndexController` тогда вот так можно поробовать. Ибо в вашем примере класс ищется от текущего namespace

Comment: `Class '\Controllers\IndexController' not found`

Comment: [вы пытаетесь гуглить хоть что либо прежде чем вопросы задавать](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5072369/1216425)?

Comment: @teran, пытаюсь и ничего из того, что я увидел не сработало. вместо риторических вопросов можете предложить решение.

Comment: я вам вроде коммент со ссылкой на ответ написал. Этот вариант не работает?

Comment: @teran, извините не разглядел. помогло дописать `()` при создание экземпляра. спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И так, распишу подробно как создать экземпляр имея на руках его название в строковой переменной.
Мы используем ООП с пространством имен. Не важно указали ли вы в начале скрипта use. Класс нужно вызывать полностью! т.е.

```
namespace a\b\

use c\d;
...
public function foo($d){ 
    $sting = '\\c\\'.$d;
    $obj = new $string();
}
```

Важно не забыть после строки указать скобки, иначе так же ничего не выйдет.

Русскоязычный ответ нашелся [здесь](http://www.cyberforum.ru/php-oop/thread408314.html)